# Defining a particular polynomial ring in some CAS (Computer Algebra System)

Tags: sage, singular, gap-system

I'm interested in defining the following polynomial [quotient ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) in some CAS (Singular, GAP, Sage, etc.):

```
R = GF(256)[x] / (x^4 + 1)
```

Specifically, `R` is the set of all polynomials of degree at most 3, whose coefficients belong to GF(256). Two examples include:

```
p(x) = {03}x^3 + {01}x^2 + {01}x + {02}
q(x) = {0B}x^3 + {0D}x^2 + {09}x + {0E}
```

Addition and multiplication are defined as the per ring laws. Here, I mention them for emphasis:

- **Addition:** The corresponding coefficients are XOR-ed (the addition law in GF(256)):

  ```
  p(x) + q(x) = {08}x^3 + {0C}x^2 + {08}x + {0C}
  ```
- **Multiplication:** The polynomials are multiplicated (coefficients are added and multiplicated in GF(256)). The result is computed modulo x^4 + 1:

  ```
  p(x) * q(x) = ({03}*{0B}x^6 + ... + {02}*{0E}) mod (x^4 + 1)
              = ({03}*{0B}x^6 + ... + {02}*{0E}) mod (x^4 + 1)
              = ({1D}x^6 + {1C}x^5 + {1D}x^4 + {00}x^3 + {1D}x^2 + {1C}x + {1C}) mod (x^4 + 1)
              = {01}
  ```

> Please tell me how to define `R = GF(256)[x] / (x^4 + 1)` in a CAS of your choice, and show how to implement the above addition and multiplication between p(x) and q(x).

Comment: Why down vote?!

Comment: Comparing with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9506705/459391), I don't see why mine is considered as "too broad" and marked for being closed.

Comment: Suggest to migrate this to https://math.stackexchange.com/ which also has tags for SageMath, Singular and GAP.